# how to test and mocking nodejs readline with jest?

Tags: node.js, jestjs, readline

I'm currently working on a method for a simple console game. And I want to test this method through jest mocking. But I'm having a hard time. Any help would be appreciated.

**index.js**

```
const readline = require("readline");
const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout,
});

class App {
  play() {
    rl.question("Input Numbers ", (userInput) => {
      const userNumbers = userInput.split("").map(Number);
      if (userNumbers.length !== 3) {
        throw new Error("[ERROR] You have to input 3 numbers");
        return;
      }
    });
  }
}

module.exports = App;
```

I tried in index.test.js with jest

```
const readline = require("readline");
const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout,
});
const App = require("../src/App");

 test("throws an error if user input 4 numbers", () => {
        const mockQuestion = jest.fn().mockImplementation((question, callback) => {
          callback("1234");
        });
        rl.question = mockQuestion;
    
        const app = new App();
    
        expect(() => {
          app.play();
    }).toThrow("[ERROR] You have to input 3 numbers");
});
```

But I got this fail message

```
Expected substring: "[ERROR] You have to input 3 numbers"
Received function did not throw
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XZpu.png)

Comment: The basic problem is that `const rl = readline.createInterface...` in each file is returning a different value for `rl`.  It seems that you think they are the same instance, but they aren't.  You can try mocking the readline package.  See https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-functions and search for `jest.mock('axios');`